# Active Record - Where IN with multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a query that needs to fetch from a table that meet two columns requirements exactly. So if I have `users` table with columns, `age` and `score`.

```
SELECT * FROM users where (age, score) IN ((5,6), (9,12), (22,44)..)
```

In my web app I am getting this pairs from an ajax request, and the number could be quite big. How do I construct an Active Record query for this?.

I am working on postgres database

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ideally, we will build a query string based on the input. Eg

```
ages_and_scores = [ [5, 6], [9, 12], [22, 44] ]
query_string = ages_and_scores.map do |pair|
  "(age = #{pair[0]} AND score = #{pair[1]})"
end.join(" OR ")
# => (age = 5 AND score = 6) OR (age = 9 AND score = 12) OR (age = 22 AND score = 44)
```

Finally, your query will be

```
User.where(query_string)
```

You may correct the logic of how to build the query string since `ages_and_scores` is in a different format to my example.

**Improvement**

```
ages_and_scores = [ [5, 6], [9, 12], [22, 44] ]
query_params = []

query_template = ages_and_scores.map{ |_| "(age = ? AND score = ?)" }.join(" OR ")
# => (age = ? AND score = ?) OR (age = ? AND score = ?) OR (age = ? AND score = ?)

User.where(query_template, *ages_and_scores.flatten)
```

Comment: In rails 5+, you can reduce by `:or` so that you don't have to write condition with string.  Refer by answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51439513/3090068

Comment: Use the improved method if you need to have the numbers read as strings.

Answer (score 5):

Another method, to reconstruct the exact query used by the OP based on a multicolumn IN clause.

A more compact form of SQL, with arguable better semantics:

```
ages_and_scores = [ [5, 6], [9, 12], [22, 44] ]
query_string    = ages_and_scores.map { |pair| "(#{pair[0]},#{pair[1]})" }.join(",")
User.where("(age, score) IN (#{query_string})")
```

Comment: this solution for my problem with composite key. great answer

Answer (score 5):

In rails 5, you can use OR, so you can do:

```
ages_and_scores = [ [5, 6], [9, 12], [22, 44] ]
ages_and_scores.map do |age, score|
  User.where(age: age).where(score: score)
end.reduce(&:or)
# => should produce something like:
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE (`users`.`age` = 5 AND `users`.`score` = 6 OR `users`.`age` = 9 AND `users`.`score` = 12 OR `users`.`age` = 22 AND `users`.`score` = 44)
```

I believe this is sql-injection free and pure ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 3):

Hey you can try this way in mysql:

```
ages_and_scores = [ [5, 6], [9, 12], [22, 44] ]

User.where("CONCAT(age,',', score) in (?)",ages_and_scores.map{|b| "#{b[0]},#{b[1]}"})
```

In PG database you can directly Concat using:

```
   (age || ' ,' || score)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel), which would help keep things DB agnostic.

```
ages_and_scores = [ [5, 6], [9, 12], [22, 44] ]
first_age, first_score = ages_and_scores.shift
t = User.arel_table
users = ages_and_scores.inject(User.where(t[:age].eq(first_age)).where(t[:score].eq(first_score))) { |query, age_score| query.or(User.where(t[:age].eq(age_score[0])).where(t[:score].eq(age_score[1]))) }
```

Essentially how this works:

1. Separate the first value pair from the array
2. Get the arel table so that you can build the query
3. Use the `inject` method from Ruby's `Enumerable` module to iterate through the rest of the array adding in all of the `or` conditions ... but starting with the initial two values in the first `where` query.

Finally, you will have an `Arel` query which returns all of the users matching your criteria ... and it should work across any DB supported by Rails (Arel).

Answer (score 0):

Base on Yuki Inoue 's comment. I have modified a little bit and it's working smoothly

```
ages_and_scores = [ [5, 6], [9, 12], [22, 44] ]
ages_and_scores.each do |age, score|
  User.where(age: age).map(score: score)
end.reduce(&:or)
# => should produce something like:
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE (`users`.`age` = 5 AND `users`.`score` = 6 OR `users`.`age` = 9 AND `users`.`score` = 12 OR `users`.`age` = 22 AND `users`.`score` = 44)
```